# Tkinter delete values in Entries, when I'm changing the Frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I have programmed a GUI with several windows with Tkinter. Each of these windows has its own entries. When I enter values into the entries and I use the method `tkraise()` to highlight another window, the values are deleted.

Does anyone know what I can do to keep the values in the entries, even if I change between the windows?

Do I have to save the values first with `entryXYZ.get()` and set the values in the entries again, if the user switch between the windows (`Frames`)?

```
import tkinter as tk

class Win1:
    

    def __init__(self, master):
        
        
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("Gap Assessment")
        self.topFrame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.topFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news', ipady = 5)
        self.A_GapFrame = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.B_GapFrame = tk.Frame(self.master)
       
        # Create a Tkinter variable
        self.gapType = tk.StringVar(self.master)
        # Dictionary with options
        self.choiceGap =  ['AFrame','BFrame']
        # self.choiceGap = sorted(self.choiceGap)
        self.gapType.set('') # set the default option
        self.ctngMenu = tk.OptionMenu(self.topFrame, self.gapType, *self.choiceGap, command=self.chioseGap_handle)
        self.ctngMenu.grid(row = 1, column =2)

    def chioseGap_handle(self, selected):

        if selected == 'AFrame':
            self.A_GapFrame.tkraise()
            self.subframe_AGap()
            self.A_GapFrame.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='news')
            
        if selected == 'BFrame':
            self.B_GapFrame.tkraise()
            self.subframe_BGap()
            self.B_GapFrame.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='news')   
                
    def subframe_AGap(self):
            self.jobNameA_text = tk.StringVar()
            self.jobNameA_entry = tk.Entry(self.A_GapFrame, textvariable = self.jobNameA_text)
            self.jobNameA_entry.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='news') 
            
    def subframe_BGap(self):
            
            self.jobNameB_text = tk.StringVar()
            self.jobNameB_entry = tk.Entry(self.B_GapFrame, textvariable = self.jobNameB_text)
            self.jobNameB_entry.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='news') 
        

        

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("+50+50")
app = Win1(root)
root.mainloop()
```

When i put some text in `self.jobNameA_text` and after that I order to switch to the `Frame` `B_GapFrame.tkraise()`, all my values in `A_GapFrame()` are deleted.

Have someone another idea to solve this?

Comment: How do you know that the content of the entry is deleted after switching to other frame?

Comment: It's hard to tell since you didn't post a [mcve], but it looks like you're recreating the widgets when you show the Frame, rather than continuing to use the widgets that are already there.  The new widgets will of course not have the contents of the old ones.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I am recreating the widgets when i show the Frame. Do you know how I can solve this?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the overall architecture of your tkinter app. Since you're using `tkraise()` to show frames, it doesn't sound like there would be a need to recreate the widgets inside one each time it's displayed — the `tkraise()` call it will make the contents of the `Frame` visible and hide any others "beneath" it. To get a definitive answer you need to do as @jasonharper suggests and post more code.

Comment: I have edited my code above. If you run this, you will see the Problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would declare my widgets in the init function then use the function to simply place them that way they persist.

```py
classMyGui:

    def __init__(self):
        # you should initialize all your variables in the init function...
        self.jobNameA_text = tk.StringVar()
        self.jobNameA_entry = tk.Entry(self.sub_AGapCanvas, textvariable self.jobNameA_text)
        self.main()

   def subframe_AGap(self):                          
        self.jobNameA_entry.place(x=130, y=120, width = 210)
        self.jobNameA_entry.configure({"background": "light green"})

    def main(self):
        self.A_GapFrame.tkraise()
        self.subframe_AGap()
        self.A_GapFrame.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='news')
```

I don't like using multiple windows I usually make a forget function as well so I can reuse the space.

```py
def subframe_AGap_forget(self):                          
        self.jobNameA_entry.place_forget()
```

That way I can no longer see the widget but it still exists for when I need it again. Hope this was helpful.

Comment: I have edited my code above. If you run this, you will see the problem. Is it the same problem which it would be solved, putting the variables in the init function?

Comment: Yes it was very helpfull. Thanks a lot. Can i ask you, why my problem was solved putting the variabled in the init function?

Comment: It is that you are only running the __init__ function once. Before every time you ran your function you would create a new entry widget that did not have your input although it appeared the same since it was created with the same code.

Comment: Thanks. Yes you are right. But the next Problem is, that the widgets from AFrame does not disappear, when i call BFrame. For this reason the BFrame contains widgets which are not supposed to be in there. Do you know what i can do in this case? You said i should hide them, but there are nearby 500 widget in 4 different Frames. Do you know how i can hide them all efficiently?

Comment: Assuming that they are all assigned to a corresponding canvas you should be able to .grid_forget() or .grid_remove() the canvas. Forget requires assignment of the grid values again, but remove will remember the values.